# PHP: text-replacement not always taking effect?

Tags: php, replace, str-replace, typography

*even though this question is based on wordpress methods the question is probably a pure php question.*

I wrote the following function to have a consistancy on my entire site with quotes, dashes and other typographic symbols.

```
add_filter('the_content', 'wr_replace_text');
add_filter('the_excerpt', 'wr_replace_text');

function wr_replace_text($text){
    $replace = array(
            '„' => '&raquo;',
            '“' => '&raquo;',
            '›' => '&raquo;',
            '“' => '&laquo;',
            '”' => '&laquo;',
            '‹' => '&laquo;',
            ' - ' => ' &mdash; ',
            ' – ' => ' &mdash; ',
            ' –,' => ' &mdash;, ',
            '...' => '&hellip;',
            '(c)' => '&copy;'
    );
    $text = str_replace(array_keys($replace), $replace, $text);
    return $text;
}
```

However, this doesn't seem to work accurately. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't.

.e.g. The following sentence has quotes in it and they don't get replaced.

> iam voluptua. “At vero” eos et a

Any idea why my replacement function wouldn't match this quotes and not replace them? If I add `'A' => 'B'` to my function I can clearly see that the function works because all "A"s get replaced by "B". However, why won't the quotes work in this case. There are other cases on my site where the quotes are replaced.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you try the [strtr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php) funtion?

Comment: sounds like an encoding problem to me, try to echo ord() of the position of the sign to see what you are dealing with

Comment: works for me: http://codepad.org/0GYTK675

Comment: `»` is a double quote ? Feels a bit strange to me...

Comment: @AlvinWong I know it strange and acutally not "correct" but in my case I simply want all possible types of quots replaced to `»` and `«`. And that is why I wonder why ` '“' => '&raquo;',` is not matched and doesn't transform the standard double quotes to `»` and `«`

Comment: @inhan same effect! Doesn't make any difference!

Comment: Again, I'm actually just wondering why the replacement doesn't have any effect? For instance imagine I want to replace `“` with `hello`. Why is this not matched -> that is my actual question.

Answer (score 1):

The quotes in your example are doublequotes (") which should be encoded as

```
'"' => &quot;
```

Comment: It's not about encoding. It's about the fact that I want all types of quotes replaced as `»` and `«`. I just wonder why `"` are not just transformed to `»`? I know that "doublequots" are different to "laquo" and "raquo". Howveer on my site I simply want all possible types of quotes always transformed into `»` and `«`.

Comment: No one an idea why it simply won't match the `"` and replace it with anything?